# Repairing a 3GP file

Tags: video, mplayer, 3gp

I was recording a video with my Droid when it froze. The resulting 3gp file was corrupted. I tried playing it in mplayer and VLC. My naive first attempt at repairing it was to try and rebuild a header based on a known good file. After prepending 12 bytes from the good file, the container was recognized by mplayer:

> Playing Videos/VID_20100729_194430-12.3gp.
>   libavformat file format detected.
>   [mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x3611f60] moov atom not found
>   LAVF_header: av_open_input_stream() failed
>   ISO: File Type Major Brand: 3GPP Profile 4
>   MPEG: Missing video stream!? Contact the author, it may be a bug :(
>   Seek failed
>   libavformat file format detected.
>   LAVF_header: av_open_input_stream() failed

The `ISO:` line shows that the container is recognized. After reading the spec a bit, I found out that audio and video are defined in "boxes" in this container. My current understanding is that a simple header isn't going to cut it.

tl;dr summary: Does anyone have any experience, in software or by hand, in repairing 3gp files? Have any suggestions for getting this video playing?

Comment: This has been responded here: http://superuser.com/questions/820482/how-can-i-repair-a-broken-3gp-mp4-file-without-a-moov-header