# How can I repair a broken 3GP/MP4 file without a moov header?

Tags: audio, mp4, audio-recording, aac, 3gp

I was recording audio two days ago and my phone suddenly died while doing so. I used MP4repair and a short clip of sound could be heard and they would be charging $80 to recover it. I thought it was too much and I don't even own a credit card, so I ruled out that possibility.

Apparently, the moov header is missing for this file. Is it possible to generate a moov header for this recording? Or better, is it possible to recover this file without having to pay those 80 Dollars?

So far I know that it is AAC audio inside a 3GP container.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a Debian-based Linux, you can use [`untrunc`](https://github.com/ponchio/untrunc). Open up a terminal window and run the following commands, one by one:

```
sudo apt-get install libavformat-dev libavcodec-dev libavutil-dev
cd ~
wget https://github.com/ponchio/untrunc/archive/master.zip
unzip master.zip
cd untrunc-master
g++ -o untrunc file.cpp main.cpp track.cpp atom.cpp mp4.cpp -L/usr/local/lib -lavformat -lavcodec -lavutil
chmod +x untrunc
```

Now, you need:

- the broken file
- a correct file – you just need a working file that you obtained from the same device

Put both into the `untrunc-master` directory. Then, run:

```
./untrunc correct.3gp broken.3gp
```

This will output a bunch of info, and it should give you a `broken.3gp_fixed.mp4` output file.

Comment: Buddy, you've just saved my life! This is awesome. I am a Windows user, so that might have been a reason why I didn't succeed solving this myself... haha
Thank you again!

Comment: Wow, I've learned something today! thx mate~

Answer (score 0):

After trying `untrunc` and various other ways, I stumbled on this:

https://codecpack.co/download/recover-mp4.html

It runs fine on `wine` and gives instructions when run without arguments.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Like what? Everything is covered, it's right there.